# Cannot save cookie with jQuery and Internet Explorer 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, internet-explorer-9

it seems I'm not able to set a cookie on IE9 and I don't understand the cause.
My goal is to set a cookie which expires after a year, and I'm using the following code

```
$.cookie( name, value, { expires:days } )
```

where days is equal to 365.
The cookie I've got is gone as soon as the session expired ( i.e. close and open the browser )
I've also tried with the following code but nothing changed

```
function setCookie( name, value, days ) {
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + days);
    var c_value = value + ( ( days==null ) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString() + "; path=/");
    document.cookie=name + "=" + c_value;
}
```

Is there something IE9 doesn't like (e.g. some characters)?
Please give me a hand with this stuff.

Best Regards
MB

Comment: does it work on other browsers? If so, please check your browser setting. IE clears cookies after you close the browser. I have been breaking my head about it once till I checked the browser settings

Comment: Yes it works on other browsers. Could you please tell me where I can find the settings you where talking about?

Comment: OK found the setting. It isn't checked so we can exclude this case. Thanks.

Comment: go to extra on the browser, and choose settings then under the tab general you'll see browser history with a checkbox. make sure the checkbox is `unchecked`

Comment: Is this still an issue?

Answer (score 1):

I found that the problem seems to be tied to the Browser configuration.
I've got a dive here:

1. Open Internet Explorer 9
2. Click on the Tools icon on the very right at the top and then on Internet Options.
3. At the top switch to the tab Privacy and click on the Advanced button.
4. Allow First-Party Cookies and Third-Party Cookies and enable Session Cookies.

All works fine now.

Could you confirm that there is nothing I can do about it but warn my users at most?