# jQuery Cookies not working as expected in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-cookie

I have Used jQuery Cookies to set a cookie variable as below

```
for(ck=1;i<= $.cookie('ck'); ck++){
   $.cookie('Answer'+answer, answer);
   $.cookie('questions'+ck, $('#quid').text());
   $.cookie('Answer'+ck, $('#'+answer).val());
   $.cookie('status'+ck, statuss);
   $.cookie('correctans'+ck, base64_decode(correctans)); 

}
```

It works Perfectly in chrome and firefox. it also works correctly in IE if the values of $.cookie('ck') is less then 9. if this is greater then 9, cookies of answer9 will be set and answer1 will be unset in IE.What have to do to resolve this?

Comment: This is the same as this post right ?
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985834/cannot-save-cookie-with-jquery-and-internet-explorer-9

Comment: no, it is not a same

Comment: Where are the values for `answer`, `correctans`, and `statuss` coming from?

Comment: Your for loop doesn't make any sense  - for(ck=1;i<= $.cookie('ck'); ck++)     Why are you using i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you have reached the maximum number of cookies in IE. See: http://browsercookielimits.iain.guru/. If you are using IE 7 or later - would suggest refactoring your cookies into HTML5 local storage: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html.

Just looking at the code it looks like you have more than 50 cookies for your domain.